# Android - Get location of touch starting from 0,0

Tags: java, android, math, touch, coordinates

I can get the coordinates of the touch just fine from:

```
event.getX();
event.getY();
```

But I want to start from an origin point of 0,0.

So I can touch anywhere on the screen, and as I drag my finger upwards, it will increase the Y by increments of 1, as I drag my finger to the right, the X will increase by increments of 1. Movement to the left will decrease the X by -1, movement downwards will decrease the Y by increments of -1.

Is there a mathematical way to do this, or better yet a class or function?

Any guidance would be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just use:

```
event.getRawX();
event.getRawY();
```

that results in **screen coordinates**,
starting at `0,0` (upper left corner)
to `width,height` (lower right corner)
depending on device, but i think thats not new to you **;)**

**--- update ---**
I think I've missunderstood you, ***sorry***..

then try this:

```
int saved_x = -1;
int saved_y = -1;

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
{
    final int action = event.getAction();
    final int pointer_index = (action & MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_MASK) >> MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_SHIFT;
    int pid = event.getPointerId(pointer_index);

    int x = (int)event.getX();
    int y = (int)event.getY();

    switch (action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK)
    {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            saved_x = x;
            saved_y = y;
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            int relative_x = x - saved_x;
            int relative_y = y - saved_y;

            //move right --> relative_x increases by 'm' pixels of movement
            //move left  --> relative_x decreases by 'm' pixels of movement
            //move down  --> relative_y increases by 'm' pixels of movement
            //move up    --> relative_y decreases by 'm' pixels of movement

            //use it :D
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            saved_x = -1; //-1 indicates "no finger on screen" -- just a feature :)
            saved_y = -1; //-1 indicates "no finger on screen" -- just a feature :)
            break;
    }

    return true;
}
```

I hope this is now what you wanted **:)**

Comment: But I want my "anchor point" (0,0) to start from where I touch (ACTION_DOWN), not from the top left corner. Then gradually increase or decrease from the point I started.

Comment: Worked perfect! Thank you so much!